# Read more csv files across different directories with python

Tags: python, csv

hey I would like to read more csv files across different directories with python. Now I can read only one file. My csv-files have a "," instead of "." (decimal point). For example, there is one folder with ten subfolders and in each subfolder are five csv-Files. How can i do it with e.g. a for loop?

```
import numpy as np
with open('data.csv') as data:
    data = np.genfromtxt((line.replace(',', '.') for line in data), delimiter=";")
```

Comment: Use `for path, dirs, files in os.walk(parent_directory)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use os.walk(), for example:

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=False):
   for name in files:
      print(os.path.join(root, name))
   for name in dirs:
      print(os.path.join(root, name))
```

Comment: Where "." means the same directory your python file is

Comment: @nico.wagner If this worked, would you mind accepting my answer by clicking the checkmark?

Comment: yes of course, sorry. I 've read this but was not on my PC. Now (in the morning) I will check it. :-)